# Installing APK programmatically in background

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have scenario where I have to download apk in background and install it 
without prompting any dialog to user. However when I try to install it using below code

```
File file = new File(filename);
if(file.exists()){
    try {
        String command;
        command = "pm install -r " + filename;
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
        proc.waitFor();
        Config.debug("Apk installed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It ask for super user access. Is there any way to install apk without super user and prompting to user?

Comment: Imagine what a HUGE security flaw would this be... Your device open to any kind of malware!!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yeah, But can you suggest me something in this case?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not that kind of developer.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar will this prompt user to view permission? I am asking this becoz the user base that I have have never used app or device.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  I am asking this becoz the user base that I have, have never used app or device before.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to install apk without super user and prompting to user?

Fortunately, no, for obvious security reasons.

**UPDATE**: One exception is on Android 5.0+ devices, if you are using the device owner system, I think there are some APIs for installing packages that are available to device owner apps. I haven't played with these yet, and it is unclear whether they would meet your needs anyway.

> I am asking this becoz the user base that I have, have never used app or device before

Then either do not give them this technology or teach them how to use this technology.

Comment: I am not sure you can install apps silently inside Lollipop, however you can do it in Marshmallow. Take a look at my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You can silently install apps starting Android Marshmallow (find info [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#afw)). You would have to be a device owner in order to accomplish the task.

You can find more help about device owner [here](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/02/10-things-to-know-about-device-owner.html). Thanks to Florent Dupont.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install the apk silently without rooting by signing your application with system signature.

Answer (score -2):

You should first look into the Android's native [Package Installer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/47fe118e0178e9d72c98073ff588ee5cf353258e/src/com/android/packageinstaller). I think you just need to extract the required functionality.

---

Specifially, if you look at this method and its OnClickListener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == mOk) {
        ...
        startActivity(newIntent);
        finish();
    } else if(v == mCancel) {
        // Cancel and finish
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Then you may notice the [InstallAppProgress](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/47fe118e0178e9d72c98073ff588ee5cf353258e/src/com/android/packageinstaller/InstallAppProgress.java) class on where the actual installer is located and the final thing to do is to call the `PackageManager`'s installPackage(...) function.

```
public void initView() {
  ...
  pm.installPackage(mPackageURI, observer, installFlags, installerPackageName);
}
```

Next step is to inspect `PackageManager` which is an abstract class. You will find that installPackage(...) function there. The bad news is that this is marked with `@hide`. This means it's not directly available to external developers.

```
/**
 * @hide
 **/
public abstract void installPackage(Uri packageUri, IPackageInstallObserver installObserver, int flags, String installerPackageName);
```

But you will be able to access the method with using reflection.

## Summary

You will reflect it using `yourContext.getPackageManager()`. Then you may call the installPackage(...) function.

The following code calls the installation:

```
try {
  getPackageManager().installPackage(packageUri, myObserver, PackageManager.INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING, "com.your.package.name");
} catch (Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

For the whole thing to work you need to declare this to your manifest or the code will fail silently.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

to get this permission you must install the APK as system which requires ROOT.

however after you have installed the APK as system it seem to work WITHOUT ROOT.

To do this, i created a signed APK and pushed it on:

```
adb push C:\Users\Example01\Desktop\release\app-release.apk /system/priv-app/MyApp.apk
```

with this i copied it to `/system/priv-app` which requires write access this is why the ROOT required.

I tested it using the debug version and when i tried it, i got the `SecurityException`.

## Conclusion

You should use a rooted device to install that as an sytem priveligied app.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: PackageManager doesn't have the method `installPackage` or it is hidden and cannot be used.