# Install APK in the background

Tags: android

I'm building an android OS which will a background installer.

When I run this code I get an error.

```
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My app isn't sign as system app. If I sign it as a system app using the platform keys. will I get still get this error or will it allow install. I have run the process with su and superuser manager, which works but I don't want to have superuser access because these devices need to be as secure as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing APK programatically in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606056/installing-apk-programatically-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install an app in background is using root or being an app system.
There is no other way to do this without having this two pre requsites!!